# forEach over array with .push into another array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm working on a Node / Mongoose / Express app and I'm having problem getting an array to update while using forEach. I'm not 100% sure what I'm missing. Does this have something to do with synchronous vs asynchronous? I may also just have the return wrong.

```
router.route('/:slug/episodes')

.get(function(req, res) {
    var episodeArray = [];
    var episodeDetails = null;
    Show.findOne({ 'slug': req.params.slug }, function(err, show) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        var episodes = show.episodes
        episodes.forEach(function(episodeID, index) {
            Episode.findById(episodeID, function(err, episode) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                episodeArray.push(episode);
            });
        });
        res.send(episodeArray)
    });
});
```

episodeArray isn't getting the episode added in and ends up just being full of null values.

Comment: Sounds like the classic async problem. See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: what's the actual problem, though? I don't see anything that describes what you see it do, and what you expected it to do instead.

Comment: Also you might have a performance issue. Why not get all the episodes from a slug at once?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the problem is that `episodeArray` isn't actually getting `episode` pushed into it. It's looping and coming up `null`

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it is. Check what the content is with a `console.log(episodeArray)` after your `episodeArray.push(episode)`. But then also notice that you have `res.send` getting called way too early, That `Episode.findById` is also async, so you'll need to wait for that to be done before `res.send`

Comment: @EricSandine Can you post the function body of `findById`? Even if it's async, you're not pushing into the array until the callback for `findById` is being fired, so that shouldn't be a problem. It sounds instead like that 2nd argument( `episode`) is null or out of scope -- because it's pushing the right number of `null`s right?

Comment: oh yeah, and @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is probably right about that `res.send(episodeArray)` at the bottom -- it shouldn't do that until all callbacks for `findById` have completed. You could check when the length of the array is sufficient and then fire the method that will call `res.send(episodeArray)`, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is suffering from a misunderstanding of how async works. First and foremost you should *read the Felix Kling link that @elclanrs posted* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). SO contributors tend to get tired of answering the same async question over and over. I haven't quite gotten that tired yet, so I'll bite for the purposes of explaining async, but I'll also suggest another option that might be a much better way to solve your problem.

**The async solution:** There are many ways to await an array of asynchronous operations to complete. `async.queue` is a popular choice. How it works is you push a set of pending operations into a queue and then tell that queue to wait until all results have been received, at which point you perform your res.send(). The code would look something like this:

```
var async = require('async');

Show.findOne({
    'slug': req.params.slug
}, function(err, show) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }

        var episodeArray = [];
        var queue = async.queue(function(episodeID, callback) {
            Episode.findById(episodeID, function(err, episode) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                episodeArray.push(episode);
                callback();
            });
        });

        // Note that forEach is synchronous.
        // The tasks will be pushed to the queue before drain()
        episodes.forEach(function(episodeID, index) {
            queue.push(episodeId);
        });

        queue.drain = function() {
            res.send(episodeArray);
        };
    });
```

**This is not the best way to solve your problem**, this is only for the purpose of demonstrating how you could fix your existing code.

As long as your episodes array is not obscenely huge, then a far better way to query your episodes might be to use mongoDB's `$in` operator, like so:

```
Show.findOne({
    'slug': req.params.slug
}, function(err, show) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }

        Episode.find({
            _id: {
                $in: show.episodes
            }
        }, function(err, episodes) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                res.send(episodes);
            });
    });
```

**Edit:**

If you want to go a bit deeper, I should also mention that mongoose supports promises, which you can use to make your code less nested and repetitive, like this:

```
Show.findOne({
    slug: req.params.slug
})
.then(function(show) {
    return Episode.find({
        _id: {
            $in: show.episodes
        }
    });
})
.then(function(episodes) {
    res.send(episodes);
})
// Any errors returned above will short circuit to the middleware next() here
.error(next);
```

Comment: I was still reading through the post to understand it better but thank you for the example. Also, using $in was perfect, I'm pretty new to deal with Mongo, I need there had to be a better way. Thanks!

Comment: I don't want to be that nitpicky, but I wrote the linked the question/answer :P or are you referring to the comment?

Answer (score 0):

You're not waiting for the asynchronous operations to finish before sending an array back to the client.

Try something like this:

```
    var togo = episodes.length;
    var error;
    episodes.forEach(function(episodeID, index) {
      Episode.findById(episodeID, function(err, episode) {
        if (err) {
          if (!error)
            error = err;
        } else
          episodeArray.push(episode);
        if (--togo === 0)
          res.send(error ? error : episodeArray);
      });
    });
```

Additionally you should really add a `return;` if you encounter an error during an async operation, in order to prevent the rest of the code from being executed.